# Use redux-persist migration to toggle value in state

Tags: redux, redux-persist

I am storing my users logged in status in redux to determine what sections of the application they should see like below

```
state: {
    user: {
        loggedIn: true
    }
}
```

I am using the code below to try to utilize migrations in redux-persist@^5.9.1 to log the user out on a version bump.

```
const migrations = {
  1: state => {
    return {
      ...state,
      user: {
        ...state.user,
        loggedIn: false
      }
    }
  }
}

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  version: 1,
  storage,
  migrate: createMigrate(migrations, { debug: true })
}
```

But the state does not seem to reconciled with the new loggedIn value, it stays `true`. I see the migrations are running in the console.

```
redux-persist: migrationKeys [1]
createMigrate.js:39 redux-persist: running migration for versionKey 1
```

From reading the documentation and looking at the example, this should be possible. I am unsure if I am doing something incorrectly or if I have misread the [documentation](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#user-content-migrations)